# BEP-20 Contract no deploy public view functions

Tags: solidity, binance, erc20, binance-smart-chain

I am studying how to make BEP-20 tokens. For this I copied the following contract in remix to be able to study it:

[Contract in BscScan](https://bscscan.com/address/0x755d31a8494bce7fd39351acbcc754ef028397de#code)

If I copy the whole file and compile it in Remix, when I deploy it it doesn't show me any getters. No public view function appears. If I look at the contract displayed on the testnet, it doesn't have any supply of tokens either.

I separated the files and libraries for a better reading. And it is then, when I try to display it, that I get the following error:

```
VM error: revert. revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance. Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

It gives me the feeling that this contract does not generate the tokens ... What am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem. As I suspected, in order to deploy the contract I have to remove everything related to uniswap and cakeswap. This displays the contract correctly.

If you wanted to deploy the contract with the uniswap interfaces in injected web3, you would need the uniswap testnet.

I found a test address for cake here:
[Binance Smart change tesnet](https://kiemtienonline360.github.io/bsc-swap-simulation/)